# How to retrieve the installation ID and confirmation ID for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

I am a systems administrator and we are getting ready to deploy Windows 7 to our users.  In our process of learning about activation, we activated a Windows 7 computer with our MAK key using Internet activation instead of doing proxy activation through VAMT 2.0.  The computer is activated, but if we need to reinstall that computer (as it is a technician computer), we'll have to re-activate it and use another one of our allotted activations.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to gather the installation ID and confirmation ID off of that Windows 7 laptop so I can paste it into or VAMT 2.0 XML (.cil) file?  That will give us the ability to just re-apply the confirmation ID should we need to reinstall that computer.  I don't need to know how to paste the installation ID and confirmation ID into the .cil file as I already know how to do that.  I'm more looking for a way to extract the installation ID and confirmation ID from the Windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the Installation ID and Activation ID by entering the following at a command prompt:

```
slmgr.vbs /dlv
```

However, I am not aware of any means to recover the confirmation that was sent by the activation server or KMS.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.  Thanks for the answer anyway.  I'll mark your post as answering my question.  If someone else posts a way to actually retrieve the confirmation ID as well, then I'll mark their post as the answer instead.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a KMS?  If you have at least 25 computers running any combination of Vista/7/Server2008/Server2008R2, it is definitely the easiest way to go.  All you need is a Win7 KMS key or a Server 2008 R2 KMS key.

Comment: I think the confirmation ID is ephemeral.

Comment: How can you get this outputted on the command line instead of in a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, but by running "slui 4" from the CLI you can re-do the online MAK activation sequence and it will produce the same activation confirmation number as it did the first time.

You can use this number, in combination with the license key, to re-activate (reinstall) windows on that same machine in the future.

Answer (score -2):

start then run and then type slui 4

Comment: This needs a lot more information to be actual helpful.